# Dynamically change height of div based on current slide height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a text slider working on the following page:

*link removed*

What I want to do is to have the containing DIV change it's height if a slide with a lot of text is loaded, so that it doesn't get cut off.

```
                var slides = $('.slide');
                var container = $('#slides ul');
                var elm = container.find(':first-child').prop("tagName");
                var item_width = container.width();
                var previous = 'prev'; //id of previous button
                var next = 'next'; //id of next button
                slides.width(item_width); //set the slides to the correct pixel width
                container.parent().width(item_width);
                container.width(slides.length * item_width); //set the slides container to the correct total width
                container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));
                resetSlides();


                //if user clicked on prev button

                $('#buttons a').click(function (e) {
                    //slide the item

                    if (container.is(':animated')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (e.target.id == previous) {
                        container.stop().animate({
                            'left': 0
                        }, 1500, function () {
                            container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));
                            resetSlides();
                        });
                    }

                    if (e.target.id == next) {
                        container.stop().animate({
                            'left': item_width * -2
                        }, 1500, function () {
                            container.find(elm + ':last').after(container.find(elm + ':first'));
                            resetSlides();
                        });
                    }

                    //cancel the link behavior            
                    return false;
```

Comment: `What I want to do is to have the containing DIV change it's height if a slide with a lot of text is loaded, so that it doesn't get cut off.` Great, nice to know. So what is your question?

Comment: Can't you fix it with CSS, instead of giving `height` to the elements, try using `min-height`

Comment: @ProEvilz I guess my question is, how can I reference the height of the active slide in the Javascript code I provided?  If I know that then I have a good idea of how I can dynamically change the height of the containing DIV when a new slide is loaded.

Comment: @user1110562 Just set the height on `#slides` to something like 550px?

Comment: @ProEvilz  I'd like it to be dynamic though.  If I set it to a fixed height, there might be a block of text down the road that goes beyond that.  Also there would be a lot of unused space for text blocks that are only 1 - 2 lines in that case.

Comment: Ok I'll post an answer in a sec. Just be aware that if you want it dynamic then the page will be moving up and down due to the height increasing & decreasing. It is not a good look...

Comment: wait, have you looked at jQuery's `height()` ?

Comment: I was trying to use  $('#carousel').height(); to set the height of that DIV on the next / prev clicks, but I just can't figure out how to get the height of the slide being loaded to pass to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following row from #slides li

```
height: 250px;
```

You should now use javascript to change the height of the "slides" element. Here's an example **hack** that works on your page, but you should obviously pretty it up some to fit your page. Run it after changing slides. (Maybe hook it up to the buttons)

```
//The second list item seems to be the visible one. This will likely fail with less than 2 items.
var newHeight = document.getElementById("slides").children[0].children[1].clientHeight;
document.getElementById("slides").style.height = newHeight+"px";
```

Get the height of the visible item and change the height of the containing element accordingly.

Comment: I've added this code in, but it doesn't seem to be getting the correct height of the active slide.  Some display properly, but the larger ones still get cut off.  I added an alert(newHeight); to see that the heights being passed are still off.

Comment: Actually it appears to be working properly on the "next" arrow click, but not on "prev".

Comment: Figured it out using a different value for .children[0].children[0].clientHeight in each button click.  Thanks!